# How to fetch onPermisesSamAccountName along with default attributes of an user in azure ad sdk java

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-sdk, azure-sdk-for-java

My azure ad sdk code to fetch all the users from a tenant is as follows

```
List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
            
                UserCollectionRequestBuilder usersClientBuilder = graphClient.users();
                UserCollectionRequest usersRequest = usersClientBuilder.buildRequest();
                do {
                    UserCollectionPage userCollectionPage = usersRequest.get();
                    users.addAll(userCollectionPage.getCurrentPage());
                    usersClientBuilder = userCollectionPage.getNextPage();
                    if (usersClientBuilder == null) {
                        usersRequest = null;
                    } else {
                        usersRequest = usersClientBuilder.buildRequest();
                    }
                } while (usersRequest != null);
                
            } catch (GraphServiceException e) {
                log.error("GraphServiceException occurred in getAllUsers() : ", e);
}
```

This code returns the following attributes

```
{
        "businessPhones": [],
        "displayName": "avinash#kumar2",
        "givenName": "Avinash",
        "jobTitle": null,
        "mail": "avinash@test.com",
        "mobilePhone": null,
        "officeLocation": null,
        "preferredLanguage": null,
        "surname": "Kumar2",
        "userPrincipalName": "avinash#kumar2@testshare.onmicrosoft.com",
        "id": "217ae76c-585b-44be-864a-e33a764ff199"
    },
```

Along with the above data, we also need to fetch onPremsisesSamAccountName. I was going through the documents of azure ad sdk and figured out that we need Optional query parameters such as $select to fetch the onPremisesSamAccountName.

When i tried this in postman it returns only the attribute we specify in select

For ex :

[image]

**But the requirement is we need to get the default attributes along with onPremsisesSamAccountName.**

Since i am using azure ad sdk in java i have tried this code, but it does not work and gives me an error

```
List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
        
            try {
                List<Option> requestOptions = new ArrayList<Option>();
                requestOptions.add(new QueryOption("$select", "'=onPremisesSamAccountName'"));
                requestOptions.add(new QueryOption("$count", "true"));
                requestOptions.add(new HeaderOption("ConsistencyLevel", "eventual"));
                Instant start = Instant.now();
                UserCollectionRequestBuilder usersClientBuilder = graphClient.users();
                UserCollectionRequest usersRequest = usersClientBuilder.buildRequest(requestOptions);
                do {
                    UserCollectionPage userCollectionPage = usersRequest.get();
                    users.addAll(userCollectionPage.getCurrentPage());
                    usersClientBuilder = userCollectionPage.getNextPage();
                    if (usersClientBuilder == null) {
                        usersRequest = null;
                    } else {
                        usersRequest = usersClientBuilder.buildRequest();
                    }
                } while (usersRequest != null);
            } catch (GraphServiceException e) {
                log.error("GraphServiceException occurred in getAllUsers() : ", e);
                
            }
```

The error is as below

```
EVERE: CoreHttpProvider[sendRequestInternal] - 408Graph service exception
Mar 19, 2024 6:57:51 PM com.microsoft.graph.logger.DefaultLogger logError
SEVERE: Throwable detail: com.microsoft.graph.http.GraphServiceException: Error code: BadRequest
Error message: Parsing OData Select and Expand failed: An identifier was expected at position 0.

GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?%24select=%3DonPremisesSamAccountName
SdkVersion : graph-java/v5.53.0


400 : 
[...]

[Some information was truncated for brevity, enable debug logging for more details]
```

Any help/suggestions please.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `$select` in your Microsoft Graph query, it will limit the query response by displaying only **specified** properties like this:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$select=onPremisesSamAccountName
```

**Response:**

[image]

To fetch <kbd>**onPermisesSamAccountName**</kbd> along with **default** attributes of users, you need to include those attributes too with **`$select`** parameter like this:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$select=businessPhones,displayName,givenName,jobTitle,mail,mobilePhone,officeLocation,preferredLanguage,surname,userPrincipalName,id,onPremisesSamAccountName
```

**Response:**

[image]

To get the same response having <kbd>**onPermisesSamAccountName**</kbd> with **default** attributes of users in Java SDK, you can refer this sample code:

```java
import com.azure.identity.ClientSecretCredential;
import com.azure.identity.ClientSecretCredentialBuilder;
import com.microsoft.graph.authentication.TokenCredentialAuthProvider;
import com.microsoft.graph.models.User;
import com.microsoft.graph.requests.GraphServiceClient;
import com.microsoft.graph.requests.UserCollectionPage;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class AzureADUserAuth {
    final String clientId = "appId";
    final String tenantId = "tenantId";
    final String clientSecret = "secret";
    final List<String> scopes = Arrays.asList("https://graph.microsoft.com/.default");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            AzureADUserAuth azureADUserAuth = new AzureADUserAuth();
            azureADUserAuth.authenticateAndFetchUsers();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void authenticateAndFetchUsers() throws Exception {
        ClientSecretCredential credential = new ClientSecretCredentialBuilder()
                .clientId(clientId).tenantId(tenantId).clientSecret(clientSecret)
                .build();

        if (null == scopes || null == credential) {
            throw new Exception("Unexpected error");
        }

        TokenCredentialAuthProvider authProvider = new TokenCredentialAuthProvider(scopes, credential);
        GraphServiceClient graphClient = GraphServiceClient.builder().authenticationProvider(authProvider).buildClient();

        // Specify the properties to retrieve using $select
        UserCollectionPage users = graphClient.users().buildRequest().select("businessPhones,displayName,givenName,jobTitle,mail,mobilePhone,officeLocation,preferredLanguage,surname,userPrincipalName,id,onPremisesSamAccountName").get();
        for (User user : users.getCurrentPage()) {
            // Print all user properties
            System.out.println("Display Name: " + user.displayName);
            System.out.println("Given Name: " + user.givenName);
            System.out.println("Surname: " + user.surname);
            System.out.println("User Principal Name: " + user.userPrincipalName);
            System.out.println("Mail: " + user.mail);
            System.out.println("Job Title: " + user.jobTitle);
            System.out.println("Mobile Phone: " + user.mobilePhone);
            System.out.println("Office Location: " + user.officeLocation);
            System.out.println("Preferred Language: " + user.preferredLanguage);
            System.out.println("Business Phones: " + user.businessPhones);
            System.out.println("ID: " + user.id);
            System.out.println("onPremisesSamAccountName: " + user.onPremisesSamAccountName);
            System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
        }
    }
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

**Reference:**
[Use query parameters to customize responses - Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters?tabs=http#select-parameter)